# How to remap username links to different locations based on page address?

Tags: url-rewriting, iis7

[On this page I found out](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/55045/how-to-change-the-destination-of-username-links/55289#comment53771_55289) how to remap username links to custom pages.

However, I on certain pages I need to remap to an administrator's user info page.  How can I modify the url rewrite rule to accomodate this?

I have two rules here - one for regular users and one for admin, which is based on which page is being used as the source.  So, I want the admin links for just certain pages, and any other page should go to the user page instead.

But using what I have here breaks the entire site.

Here is the rule:

```
    <rule name="Admin Info Link" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*/)?_layouts/userdisp.aspx$" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="/SitePages/user.aspx?userID={C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
        <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="*/whatsite/whatpage*" />
                            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="ID=(\d+)" />
        </conditions>
    </rule>        
    <rule name="User Info Link" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*/)?_layouts/userdisp.aspx$" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="/SitePages/user.aspx?userID={C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
        <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="ID=(\d+)" />
        </conditions>
    </rule>
```

How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be accomplished by specifying  more *narrow match pattern for url*

For example, let's discuss the scenario, where requests from:

```
http://{ServerName}/_layouts/teamsiteA/userdisp.aspx?ID=1
```

should be redirected to:

```
http://{ServerName}/SitePages/UserInfoA.aspx?userID=1
```

and requests from:

```
http://{ServerName}/_layouts/teamsiteB/userdisp.aspx?ID=1
```

should be redirected to:

```
http://{ServerName}/SitePages/UserInfoB.aspx?userID=1
```

XML Rules declaration for that case may look like this:

```
                <rule name="Team Site A User Info Link" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*/)?teamsiteA/_layouts/userdisp.aspx$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="ID=(\d+)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="/SitePages/UserInfoA.aspx?userID={C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Team Site B User Info Link" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*/)?teamsiteB/_layouts/userdisp.aspx$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="ID=(\d+)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="/SitePages/UserInfoB.aspx?userID={C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
```

Comment: Thanks again, vgrem - this works perfectly.  I should've figured that out myself, actually.  I feel a bit ashamed now.

Comment: :) I'm glad I could help